# C# Web App Conditional statement that can accept results from a SQL Query

Tags: c#, arrays, conditional-statements

I am working on an older CMS (C#, Visual Studio 2005, .NET 2.0) that splits visibility of an object based on a user's id and that user's relationship to a vendor ID. I currently have a conditional that has worked so far that simply does this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If the current user is Special Vendor 1, or has a parent Id of Special Vendor 1 then load the "Special Vendor 1" documents
        if ((CurrentUser.Vendor.Id == 3) || (CurrentUser.Vendor.ParentVendor.Id == 3) || (CurrentUser.Vendor.ParentVendor.Id == 1) || (CurrentUser.Vendor.Id == 374) || (CurrentUser.Vendor.ParentVendor.Id == 374))

        {
            hypCatalogAccessLink.NavigateUrl = "documents/SpecialVendor1_Catalog_Access_v3 3_2011_08SV1.pdf";
            hypCatalogAccessLink.Text = "Download Special Vendor 1 Catalog Access";
            hypCatalogAccessLink.Target = "_blank";
        }
        // Another Special Vendor (Special Vendor 2)
        else if ((CurrentUser.Vendor.Name == "Special Vendor 2") || (CurrentUser.Vendor.ParentVendor.Name == "Special Vendor 2"))
        {
            hypCatalogAccessLink.NavigateUrl = "documents/SpecialVendor2_Catalog_Access_v3.3_2011_08_SV2.pdf";
            hypCatalogAccessLink.Text = "Download Special Vendor 2 Catalog Access";
            hypCatalogAccessLink.Target = "_blank";
        }
        else // Use Generic Vendor Catalog as default
        {
            hypCatalogAccessLink.NavigateUrl = "documents/Generic_Catalog_Access_v3 3_2011_08.pdf";
            hypCatalogAccessLink.Text = "Download Generic Catalog Access";
            hypCatalogAccessLink.Target = "_blank";
        }
    }
```

What I want to do, now that we have many, many child vendors of Special Vendor 1, is to pull all the child vendors from a stored procedure, which will update results as child vendors are added, in real-time. However, I do not know how to integrate a set of integer results into a conditional statement. My first instinct is to use a foreach in the first condition, but I have no experience doing such things. I can call my stored procedure with 
    EXEC GetAllSV1ChildVendors 
Which returns a list of 24 vendors that I want to filter out for Special Vendor 1 visibility access.
 Should I populate an array? Is there a more direct access method to the results of the stored procedure? Any help is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you store your list of vendor ids in a List, you could do

```
if (VendorList.Contains(CurrentUser.Vendor.Id) ...
```

Comment: Can I populate the list from the results of a stored procedure?

Comment: Sure.  Just loop through your results and add them to the list.  You could also populate the list with a LINQ query.

Comment: VS 2005, so no LINQ options here, unfortunately.

Comment: The Contains method is not a part of Linq - the List class has this method in .NET 2.0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Right.  I was trying to point out that you could use LINQ to create the list instead of manually iterating through it.  But however you build the list, you can use Contains() to check for existence of an item.